# Validating Format for Numbers and letters in specific position of a string

Tags: c#

I have the following String character consisting of two letters followed by four numbers, followed by two letters, such as xy1234xy. I need to be able to determined if the user entry meets this criteria.

For other projects, I used a `Take`, `Skip` as I would rather not use Regix if there is an alternative:

I have used something like this in the past but having issues with the mid section:

```
public static void MemberNumberInput(string checkNumberLetter)
{
IsValidInput = (checkNumberLetter.Take(2).All(char.IsLetter) &
(checkNumberLetter.Skip(2).All(char.IsDigit) & 
(checkNumberLetter.Take(2).All(char.IsLetter) & 
(checkNumberLetter.Trim().Length == 8))));
}
}
```

Thanks everyone:

Guy

Comment: Regex? Or checking explicitly each position in the string?

Comment: Hey Karel: The Position has to match as well as the character type: So it has to start with 2 letters 4 numbers and 2 letters in the above format.

Comment: "I'm not going to show you any effort I have made, but please don't include the easy and proper solution as I would rather not use it." isn't really the best way to ask for help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about like this?

```
string myString = "xy1234xy";
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$"))
{
    // Do something
}

^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/IuOjiqPVG3IyxEHa)

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/CRV5pO).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I usually (personally) try to find other alternatives to Regix. You example is very interesting refreshing and extremely helpful. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Learn regular expressions.  The great thing is they're (basically) the exact same in all languages, used in command-lines, IDEs, some website searches, and more.  And it helps you get hired at google.  https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/five-essential-phone-screen-questions

Answer (score 1):

If you *absolutely cannot* use a regex, I'd think the most straightforward way is to just check them one-by-one:

```
return checkNumberLetter.Length == 8 &&
  checkNumberLetter[0].IsLetter() &&
  checkNumberLetter[1].IsLetter() &&
  checkNumberLetter[2].IsDigit() &&
  checkNumberLetter[3].IsDigit() &&
  checkNumberLetter[4].IsDigit() &&
  checkNumberLetter[5].IsDigit() &&
  checkNumberLetter[6].IsLetter() &&
  checkNumberLetter[7].IsLetter();
```

You could do this in a for loop or some set of LINQ queries, but my opinion is this is the simplest and most straightforward option.